# selenium webdriver-this my login button tag how to identidy which method is used for this case

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I just tried with the selenium I want to click login button this is my tags which class methods will work

```
<input tabindex="9" class="loginbtngoBT btn btn-primary email-btn-primary" type="submit" value="Log in">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log in']"));
```

Comment: custom xpath?  expain him to how to use custom xpath :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try: `ByCssSelector, using=".loginbtngoBT"`, also can work: `ByCssSelector, using="input[type='submit']`